# How to invest in stocks / Mutual funds in Japan?

Tags: taxes, stocks, investing, mutual-funds, japan

Being a foreign national, I've been living in Japan for more than 5 years. I'm very interested in learning about stocks investing and want to start investing in Japan but how I don't how to invest here, what is the tax rate for capital gains etc?

Could someone please give some insights on how to get started?

Answer (score 3):

You're asking two different questions: 1. how to invest on the Japanese exchanges, and 2. what the tax rates are.
The easiest way to invest on the Japanese exchanges, if you're American, is to use a US or European broker that trades on worldwide exchanges. Interactive Brokers is one that can trade stocks on the Tokyo exchange and has low fees.
For Japanese tax questions you need to consult a Japanese tax accountant or lawyer, a brokerage is not going to give you advice about that. If you are American you may also be subject to US tax on dividends.

Answer (score 0):

Contact a broker and open an account.  Look at the membership lists for the Tokyo Stock Exchange and Osaka Stock Exchanges to find a broker you might like to use.

They might be able to point you to information about capital gains and so on.